# A coincidence between the Lambert cube, Lobell polyhedron, and hyperbolic 3-manifolds?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds

**I. Lambert cube**  $\mathfrak L(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$

In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0de0/af4e7877fdebf45ad3be1af7faa04e787302.pdf?_ga=2.50967721.1479578514.1561033498-700242977.1518689157) (p.8), we find the volume $V$ of the hyperbolic *Lambert cube* for the special case $\alpha=\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha_3$ as

$$V_\alpha = \int_x^\infty \ln\left(\frac1{t^2}\left(\frac{t^2-\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}\right)^3\right)\frac{dt}{t^2+1}$$

where $x$ is the positive root of $x^4-(1+3\tan^2\alpha)x^2-\tan^6\alpha =0$. Hence,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\alpha &x& V_{\alpha} & 8V_{\alpha}\\
\hline
\pi/3 &\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}2\right)^{3/2}& 0.324423 & \color{brown}{2.59538}\\
\pi/4 &\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\right)^{3/2}& 0.538275 & \color{blue}{4.30620}\\
\pi/5 &\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}2\right)^{3/2}& 0.658081 & 5.26465\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**II. Lobell polyhedron $L(n)$**

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603552.pdf) (p.33), we find [the volume](http://oeis.org/A321209) (using a different formula) of $L(5)$ as

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & L(n) & V_n\\
\hline
5 & L(5) & \color{blue}{4.30620}\\
6 & L(6) & 6.02304\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**III. Closed hyperbolic 3-manifolds**

On a hunch, I checked those volumes in the [Hodgson & Weeks census](http://plouffe.fr/simon/constants/table216.txt) and found,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Dehn filling}& \text{Symmetry} & \text{Volume}\\
\hline
m160(-3, 2) & D6 & \color{brown}{2.59538}\\
\hline
s648(-5, 1) & D4 & \color{blue}{4.30620}\\
s921(-3, 1) & D2 & 4.30620\\
m400( 4, 1) & Z/2 & 4.30620\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

**IV. Questions**

1. Why are the volumes for $\alpha =\pi/3, \pi/4$ and $L(5)$ found in the census?
2. Conversely, why for $\alpha =\pi/5$ and $L(6)$ are they NOT present?

Comment: A first check for a possible explanation might be trying to figure out whether the fundamental domains of those 3-manifolds could be (scissors congruent to) said polyhedras.

Answer (score 5):

Let me make a remark about the first question and then try to answer the second.

For the first question, using snappy's arithmetic computations (available when using snappy as a sage module), it looks like m400(4,1), s648(-5,1), s921(-3,1) are likely 60 fold covers of the quotient of $H^3$ by an arithmetic tetrahedral group $\Gamma(3,3,5,2,2,2)=\langle x,y,z| x^3,y^5,z^3, (yz^{-1})^2,(zx^{-1})^2,(xy^{-1})^2\rangle$ (see

*Maclachlan, Colin; Reid, Alan W.*, The arithmetic of hyperbolic 3-manifolds, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 219. New York, NY: Springer. xiii, 463 p. (2003). [ZBL1025.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1025.57001). (Especially pages 144, 415
for more information on tetrahedral groups.)

For an exact representation of this group, you can use Grant Lakeland's notes available from his website:
[Matrix group computations](http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~gslakeland/tetrahedral_realizations.pdf). It's possible this group (or its index 2 supergroup $\Gamma(3,2,5,2,2,4)$) is the symmetries of the dodecahedron corresponding to $L(5)$, but I don't know if that is written down anywhere.

For the second question,  $\alpha=\pi/5$ and $(6)$ are likely not in the Hodgson-Weeks census because they are too complicated. The Hodgson-Weeks census is a set of 11,031 fillings of ideal triangulations with 7 or fewer tetrahedra such that (experimentally) the injectivity radius is sufficiently large (I think above .3). So if $L(6)$ can only be obtained from filling an ideal triangulation with 8 or more tetrahedra then it won't appear here.

This appears to be the case. Or more precisely, as the geodesic cut-off doesn't seem to be a restriction for $L(6)$, it's seems the answer is that nothing with a fundamental domain with a volume like that of $L(6)$ can be obtained from filling a cusped manifold with 7 or fewer tetrahedra. I would conjecture that the same could be said for $\alpha=\pi/5$, but I don't know what its shortest geodesic is in that case.

Comment: Your guess about the tetrahedral group is true, simply because this tetrahedron tiles the dodecahedron (the stabiliser of one of the vertices is $A_5$ or $S_5$ and its orbit gives the tiling). It is possible to identify exactly which group this is. I'm not sure all details are in MacLachlan--Reid.